# Stepper not updating

Tags: ios, swift, uistepper

I have two steppers in a ViewController, one called `homeStepper` the other called `awayStepper`. When I run the app on my phone the value for homeStepper changes just fine, however nothing happens when I try to use the awayStepper. I added log statements and they just show the value of the stepper never changing. It always sits at 0 no matter how many times I push either button on it. Here is my code: https://github.com/Zach443/ScoreKeeper/blob/c83d5eeaadafaad4f093437679d26a8b55ef5dd8/ScoreKeeper/ViewController.swift

Comment: When you press the stepper does the "awayStepper pressed!" NSLog never appear? (Asside, the general advice is to post code snippets directly here rather than links).

Comment: @AliBeadle That log shows up, and the one before that showing the value always says 0. Same for the awayScore label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
approxAwayScore = homeStepper.value
```

Should be

```
approxAwayScore = awayStepper.value
```

Comment: @Zach443 No probs. Cut-and-paste - we have all been there! Also, you are passing score into updateScore but never using it?

Comment: yep... I've been voicing around with ideas and I forgot to remove that